# Which Informal Fallacy(ies)? 'Thou shalt not bear false witness against thy neighbor.'

Tags: fallacies

<sub>Source: p 130-131, *With Good Reason, An Introduction to Informal Fallacies* (2000 6 ed) by [York U. Prof. S. Morris Engel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S._Morris_Engel).</sub>

> [p 130 :] Identify the fallacy of ambiguity — equivocation, amphiboly, 
>   accent, hypostatization, division, or composition — that is committed in, or that could result from, each of the following. Explain the error committed in each case.
>
> [p 131 :] 15. Thou shalt not bear false witness against thy neighbor.

Conjecture: From the textbook's supplied answers to a few exercises for each set (but not to the question above), I am inferring the author to intend only 1 Informal Fallacy for each exercise, selected from only the ones named in the instructions (though I know of the simultaneous occurrence of Informal Fallacies, in general).

Attempt: By the Process of Elimination (because none of the other 5 Fallacies named apply), I would propound 'Accent' because the meaning of 15 can be ambiguated by which word is accented. For example, someone may accent the 2nd-person pronoun 'Thou' or 'Thy' (vs. the impersonal 3rd person 'One' or 'Everyone') to reference specifically the addressee, or the noun 'neighbour' to reference specifically the addressee's neighbour.

Comment: My first thought looking at this is ... I don't see an immediate informal fallacy for at least two reasons. First, I don't know if it's meant to be an argument. No argument = no fallacy. Second, just because things are in printed books doesn't mean they make sense or are good examples.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a fallacy *that could result from* this statement, not for a fallacy in the statement itself.

An obvious fallacy that could result from this statement would be to make the wrong assumption that "thy neighbours" means explicitly only people living nearby or who are personally close to you, and that it is perfectly allowable to spread lies about people who live further away.

Comment: Yes, that would arguably be the fallacy of contextomy (quotation out of context), leading to equivocation (switching to a different sense of the polysemous word "neighbor").