# Which Informal Fallacy(ies)? "That means now and forever, because I am a Yankee, and Yankees do not throw rocks."

Tags: fallacies

<sub>Source: pp 253, 258. *With Good Reason, An Introduction to Informal Fallacies* (2000 6 ed) by [York U. Prof. S. Morris Engel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S._Morris_Engel).</sub>

> [p 253 :] Identify the fallacy of relevance—personal attack. mob appeal, 
>   appeal to pity, appeal to authority, appeal to ignorance, or appeal to fear—that is committed in, or that would result from, 
>   each of the following. Explain the error committed in each case.
>
> [p 259 :] 42. Billy Martin, after resigning as Yankee manager. saying 
>   why he would make no further comment: "That means 
>   now and forever, because I am a Yankee, and Yankees 
>   do not throw rocks."

Conjecture: Please see [the one here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/36903/8572) that pertains to all these exercises.

Attempt: By the Process of Elimination (because none of the other named Fallacies apply), I have narrowed the choices to, but cannot decide between,

- 'Appeal to Authority (in particular, to Tradition [pp 244-245])' : Billy Martin might be following tradition of never reproaching one's own team or employer.
- or 'Appeal to 'Fear': Billy Martin might fear retaliation from reproaching the Yankees, or be threatening retaliation to those who do so.

Comment: Seriously, did the book say Martin's statement was a *fallacy*?  Maybe it is supposed to be the fallacy of trying to keep your dignity in a difficult situation.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty  No; not directly or explicitly. But it is implied because of what I wrote in the linked Conjecture above.